# Which line in this code making error with "datepicker is not a function"?

Tags: jquery

First of all, I'm sorry that I'm asking this again since even though I found similar questions in stackoverflow but I don't get it.
I keep getting 
`JSfeatures_DP.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function.`
I included several scripts in my code because I have many JS features. And then, I can't tell which code is needed while which is not.

This is base.blade.php file

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <div>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>DemoProject!!</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        {{--datepicker--}}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        {{--darkmode--}}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/JSfeatures_DP.js') }}"></script>

        {{-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/js"></script> --}}

        <div class="container">
            @yield('main')
        </div>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is datepicker function I made in JSfeatures_DP.js.

```
    function Calendar(self){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(self).datepicker({
                inline: true,
                firstDay: 0,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
            }).datepicker("show");
        });
    }
```

---

One of the datepicker call

```html
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>" class="form-control" name="date" onfocus="
                        Calendar(self);
                        highlightInput(this);
                    ">
```

Comment: You are including multiple copies of jQuery. Don't do that

Comment: How do you call the `Calendar` function? What is the `self` parameter?

Comment: @Phil I thought 3.4.1 is latest version so I comment out 1.71 darkmode, then I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` error @_@

Comment: @Geshode I added code for you ; )

Comment: @MuraliNepalli Yeah it works... I thought `self` select itself automatically so I don't need something like `id="self"`...  Seems it ain't eh?

Comment: @JunoJ: It seems "self" was referring to "window", not your datepicker. So send "this" instead of "self". Please check the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Self" is referring to "window", So either you should use $("#self") in your Calendar method or you should pass "this" as a parameter instead of "self". You don't need to wrap the the code inside $(document).ready, DOM would be obviously ready by then.

https://jsfiddle.net/9z16d0t2/1/

```
   <input type = "text" onfocus="calendar(this)">  

   function calendar(datepicker){          
        $(datepicker).datepicker({
          inline: true,
          firstDay: 0,
          showOtherMonths: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        }).datepicker("show");        
    }
```

OR

```
 <input type = "text" id ="self" onfocus="calendar()">

  function calendar(){          
      $("#self").datepicker({
        inline: true,
        firstDay: 0,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
      }).datepicker("show");        
    }
```

Comment: Resolved! thx : ) how unbelievable that if I change like this `function Calendar(this){
    $(this).datepicker({`, it shows errors in other features not datepicker... Anyway thank you!